# List of arrays containing tuples(?)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been running into a TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple. However, I can't figure out how to fix it, as I'm apparently misunderstanding where the tuple is (wasn't even aware there would be one from what I understand). Shouldn't my index and the values that I'm passing in all be integers?

```
def videoVolume(images):
   """ Create a video volume from the image list.

   Note: Simple function to convert a list to a 4D numpy array.

    Args:
        images (list): A list of frames. Each element of the list contains a
                       numpy array of a colored image. You may assume that each
                       frame has the same shape, (rows, cols, 3).

    Returns:
        output (numpy.ndarray): A 4D numpy array. This array should have
                                dimensions (num_frames, rows, cols, 3) and
                                dtype np.uint8.
    """
    output = np.zeros((len(images), images[0].shape[0], images[0].shape[1],
                      images[0].shape[2]), dtype=np.uint8)

    # WRITE YOUR CODE HERE.
    for x in range(len(images)):
        output[:,:,:,:] = [x, images[x,:,3], images[:,x,3], 3]



    # END OF FUNCTION.
    return output
```

Comment: Is that the complete code? also what is the traceback?

Comment: It is the complete code.
Traceback:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment_test.py", line 377, in <module>
    if not test_videoVolume():
  File "assignment9_test.py", line 73, in test_videoV
    usr_out = assignment.videoVolume(img_list)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\assignment.py", line 53, in videoVolume
    output[:,:,:,:] = [x, images[x,:,3], images[:,x,3
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: `images[x,:,3]` is short for `image[(x,:,3)]`.  The stuff inside the `[]` is a `tuple`.  `np.array` can handle that kind of indexing, a plain list cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tuple referred to in the error message is the `x,:,3` in the index here:

```
images[x,:,3]
```

The reason this is happening is that `images` is passed in as a *list* of frames (each a 3d numpy array), but you are trying to access it as though it is itself a numpy array. (Try doing `lst = [1, 2, 3]; lst[:,:]` and you'll see you get the same error message).

Instead, you meant to access it as something like `images[x][:,:,:]`, for instance

```
for x in range(len(images)):
    output[x,:,:,:] = images[x][:,:,:]
```

Comment: This makes so much more sense and fixes my problem, thank you!